# Apache 2.4.6 VirtualHost DocumentRoot config for SSL is ignored

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl, apache-virtualhost

Apache is ignoring the DocumentRoot setting in my VirtualHost configuration.

The site loads the correct DocumentRoot via **http** on port 80 but when accessed over **https** on port 443 it loads the apache's default DocumentRoot at `/var/www/html` instead of `var/www/mysite`.

The SSL certificate does load correctly, it's just the DocumentRoot that is being ignored.

I'm running Apache/2.4.6 on CentOS.

Configuration as follows:

```
# /etc/httpd/vhost.d/mysite.mylabserver.com_httpd.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.labserver.com
        ServerAlias mysite

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mysite.mylabserver.com
        ServerAlias mysite

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl-certs/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl-certs/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: try with <VirtualHost _default_:443> insted of *:443

Comment: Same outcome using `default:443`

Comment: there is a config file on /etc/httpd/conf.d called ssl.conf (or something similar) holding on the default ssl config. You have three options then... edit that file, remove that file (not recommended) or use a named virtual host <VirtualHost your_ip_address_or_host_name:443>. Let me know if that helps and I will post it as an answer

Comment: Cheers @NoelCarcases, I will try.

Comment: Thanks @NoelCarcases, the ssl.conf was conflicting with my config. I renamed it ssl.template and only had to copy across the `Listen 443 https` to my config (outside the VirtualHost).  Please include in answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a config file on

/etc/httpd/conf.d called ssl.conf (or something similar)

holding on the default ssl config.

You have three options then...

1. edit that file
2. remove that file (not recommended)
3. use a named virtual host .

Please keen in mind to copy the Listen 443 to your file.

Let me know if that helps